# How to change object reference inside another object in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a situation where some objects come from an external Jar. There is an `object X` used from other `object`s like this:

```
object X {
    def foo() = ....
... more methods to follow
}

object A {
    def bar() = X.foo()
    ...few more methods using X
}

object B {
    def baz() = X.baz()
     ...few more methods using X
}

...other objects using X...
```

All that objects belong to the same Jar package and I need to use the classes `A`,`B`,etc but with a different reference than X (would be my `local X`).
Is there a way to replace somehow `X` inside my project that is using a jar defined in that way?

Comment: it is not my code and I cannot change it.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed that. I just was ranting because you are now in a big problem because someone didn't design their code correctly. Why do you need to replace X?

Comment: I have to inject different cloud configurations that "wrap" Spark processes and the code is meant to run on a "physical" env only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

In long, it is possible but it's more like a hack rather than a proper solution.

You can redefine X within the same package name as original X and then rely on classloader order of jars to load your X first.

The correct solution is a redesign of your program so it allows "injection" of implementations. For example in this way

```scala
trait X {
    def foo() = ....
... more methods to follow
}

object X extends X
object Y extends X

object A {
    def bar(x: X) = x.foo()
    ...few more methods using X
}

object B {
    def baz(x: X) = x.baz()
     ...few more methods using X
}
```

Comment: It is not my program, I mean I cannot change it (so not redesign it)